# React Native FlatList with columns, Last item width

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a FlatList to show a list of items in two columns

```
<FlatList style={{margin:5}}
  data={this.state.items}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id }
  renderItem={(item) => <Card image={item.item.gallery_image_url} text={item.item.name}/> }
/>
```

The card component is just a view with some styles:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5, backgroundColor: '#ddd', height: 130}} ></View>
```

It is working fine, but if the number of items is odd, the last row only contains one item and that item stretches to the full width of the screen.

How can I set the item to the same width of the others?

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Theres a few things you can try here.

A)   Setting a pre-defined width for the card ( Maybe equal to the height you've set? ). Then you can use `alignItems` in order to have the card positioned in the middle or on the left - Unsure as to which you wanted here.

B)   If there are an even number of cards, you could add an empty View at the end in order to fill this space. I find this method pretty clunky but useful when trying to leave space for future elements.

C)   Simply use `alignItems: 'space-between`, i like to use this to center items, but you would have to define the width, or use something like `flex:0.5`

I suggest researching more into flexbox to help you with this, as it is hard to tell the context of this situation. I'm assuming the above methods will help, but if not, here are some links for you to look at -

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox (CSS Tricks)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Layout with Flexbox (React Native)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)

<del>[Video Tutorial (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC4GMP9r6bY)</del> <sub>*Link Broken*</sub>

Hope this helps. If you need any further clarification - just ask

Comment: B is a reasonable hack. Option A is redundant, one can simply set to align like those by adding flexWrap. What's the purpose of numColumns in that case?

Comment: container flex:4 if flatlist column is 4. item flex:0.25, this works.

Answer (score 104):

for your case use **flex: 1/2**

therefore: Your **item** should have **flex** of 1/(number of columns) if you have 3 columns your item should have flex:1/3

Comment: when I am giving flex: 1/2, the width of the last item bigger than the previous items, How can we fix this any idea please

Comment: The issue with the last row being slightly wider might have to do with margins; try wrapping the item in a View that has no margins.

Comment: @JamesWestman or add an empty view with the same margin properties to the back

Answer (score 31):

#### This is the cleanest way to style a `FlatList` with columns and spaced evenly:

```
    <FlatList style={{margin:5}}
        numColumns={2}                  // set number of columns 
        columnWrapperStyle={style.row}  // space them out evenly
        
        data={this.state.items}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id }
        renderItem={(item) => <Card image={item.item.gallery_image_url} text={item.item.name}/> }
    />       

    const style = StyleSheet.create({
        row: {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "space-around"
        }
    });
```

Comment: This will not work as expected when no of columns is 3, you will see empty space in between for the last row if total items are multiple of 5.

Answer (score 20):

You can try to get the current width of the device via Dimensions, do some math based on the number of columns you want to render, minus off the margins and set that as the minWidth and maxWidth.

For example:

```
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const itemWidth = (width - 15) / 2;

<View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5, backgroundColor: '#ddd', minWidth: {this.itemWidth}, maxWidth: {this.itemWidth}, height: 130}} ></View>
```

Answer (score 10):

The reason for it is your Card have style `flex: 1`, so it will try to expand all the space remain. 
You can fix it by add `maxWidth: '50%'` to your Card style

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5, backgroundColor: '#ddd', height: 130, maxWidth: '50%'}} ></View>
```

Answer (score 5):

@Emilius Mfuruki suggestion is good, but if you have text with varying length it doesn't work perfectly. Then use this width inside your item view:

```js
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
const itemWidth = (width - (MarginFromTheSide * 2 + MarginInBetween * (n-1))) / n;
```

In FlatList use:

```js
columnWrapperStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          }}
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: I did something similar. Just to clarify, `MarginFromTheSide` is the screen horizontal margin, while `MarginInBetween` is the margin between each column. So you get the available width for the `FlatList`, remove the margin and divide it by the amount of columns, so you have the width of each item :)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is do the math.
Imagine we have 2 View for each Row and we want to give 10 margin to every side it will look something like that:

[image]

As you see in the image above each View have 2 margins in horizontal. (inside of red rectangle)
So we have to subtract the product of margin, number of column and 2 from the width.

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const {width} = Dimensions.get("window")
const column = 2
const margin = 10
const SIZE = (width - (margin * column * 2)) / column
<View style={{ margin: 10, width: SIZE }} ></View>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried some of the solutions above but I still had some problems with the margins on the last item (2 columns list).

[image]

My solution was simply wrapping the item into a parent container, leaving the original container with `flex: 1` and the parent container of the item with `flex: 0.5` so it would take the margin correctly.

```
itemContainer: {
  flex: 0.5,
},
itemSubContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  marginHorizontal: margin,
},
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as the vertical height becomes limited to 0.5

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers have worked perfectly for me so I post my own answer:

- **works with padding and margins**
- the last element will always have the correct size

```jsx
<FlatList
  data={data}
  numColumns={2}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => {
  const lastItem = index === data.length - 1;
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 8, maxWidth: lastItem ? '50%' : '100%' }}>
      ...
    </View>
  )}}
/>
```

**Note**: change maxWidth according to number of columns

Result:

[image: reactFlatlist]

Comment: Can this be made to work using a StyleSheet?

Comment: Yes, until you can set the last element width dynamically

Comment: A better question would probably have been "how"? Is it as simple as defining a style, using it and then over-riding some of the values? How would that work with this syntax?

Answer (score 2):

**A simple way with flex**

```
 <FlatList style={{margin:5}}
  data={this.state.items}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id }
  renderItem={({item, index}) => {
  const lastItem = index === this.state.items.length - 1;
  return (
    <View style={{flex: lastItem ? 1 / 2 : 1 }}>
      <Card image={item.gallery_image_url} text={item.name}/>
    </View>
  )}}
/>
```

Comment: Just a fix in case you want to have margins or padding: add `maxWidth: lastItem ? '50%' : '100%'` after `flex: lastItem ?...`

Comment: Can this be made to work with StyleSheet?

Comment: Try something like 
`return (<View style={styles({lastItem}).itemContainer}><Card image={item.gallery_image_url} text={item.name}/></View>)
....
const styles = ({lastItem}) => StyleSheet.create({itemContainer : {flex: lastItem ? 1 / 2 : 1}};`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and instead of fixing it with CSS flexbox, I simply push a null element to the array if the array's length is odd number.

```html
const data = [1,2,3];

if (data.length % 2 > 0) {
    data.push(null);
}
```

This is of course not a proper solution. Just wish to share an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is efficient or not but works like charm.

```js
// I have 4 columns
let rem = column_count - images.length % column_count;
let blanks = Array(rem).fill( {} )
images.push(blanks);

<Flatlist
   data={images}
   ...
  />
```

// Note
instead of using {}, you can use {key:value} to handle undesired result by checking these blank item

Here is my actual working code

```js
...
 let blanks = Array.from({length:4-photos.length%4}).map(i=>({}))
  photos.push(blanks)

  return ( 
    <View style={styles.container}>
         <FlatList
          numColumns={4}
          data={photos}
...
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of gallary grid view in React native]

Answer (score -1):

just use flex:0.5 and width:'50%'

Answer (score -1):

Create an array with odd number of images in it, like:

```
const images = [
  require('./../...jpg'),
  require('./../...jpg'),
  require('./../...jpg'),
  require('./../...jpg'),
  require('./../...jpg'),
];
```

And then, use the code given below,

```
const App = () => {
const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <Image
    source={item}
    style={{
      width: '50%',
      height: 200,
    }}
    resizeMode="cover"
  />
 );

return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 10,}}>
      <FlatList
        columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
        keyExtractor={(_, index)=> index.toString()}
        data={images}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  )
};
export default App;
```

[**Working Example**](https://snack.expo.io/@pratik_adh/92f850)

Comment: your last image still stretches the entire view.