# collectionView in React Native last cell taking 100 percentage width , How to stop this

Tags: react-native, binding, grid

IN React Native I am trying to create a Grid cell. Problem is, when the cell is one then it takes 100 percentage width. I have needed all cell will be equal height width. if the cell is one or more, Not need to change the width. Here are my code and screenshot, see last cell width.

```
  render() {
        let imageURL = "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/"
        let partofURL = "women/"
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header>
                </Header>
                <Content padder>
                <FlatList
                        data={this.state.ary_data}
                        numColumns={3}
                        itemWidth={150}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                       <View style={{
                                flex: 1, margin: 5,
                                backgroundColor: '#ddd', borderColor: '#000000',
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 130

                            }} >
                                <Grid> 
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.didselectoncell(item.id)}>
                                    <Row style={{ height: '20%' }} >
                                        <Text>name:{item.name}</Text>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row style={{ height: '20%' }}>
                                        <Text style={{textAlign:'center',width:'100%'}}>Detail:{item.detail}</Text>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row >
                                        <Image
                                            style={{ width: 70, height: 70,
                                                backgroundColor:'#000000',
                                                marginLeft:'auto',
                                                marginRight:'auto' }}
                                            source={{ uri:  imageURL + partofURL + item.id + '.jpg' }}>
                                        </Image>
                                    </Row>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </Grid>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}/>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Refer [React Native FlatList with columns, Last item width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502954/react-native-flatlist-with-columns-last-item-width)