# Prevent alone item going 100% width on FlatList that has 2 columns in React-Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

I got a FlatList with `numColumns={2}`, inside this FlatList, I render a Native-Base Card item. 
The idea is to have a list of cards and each of those, occupying the 50% of the parent container.
But I realized that if for example I have 3 items, the item below would occupy the 100% of the width due to `flex: 1` on the card style.

How can I make the item that is alone to go only up to 50% width no matter what?

This is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                numColumns={2}
                style={ styles.cardContainer }
                keyExtractor={ this._keyExtractor }
                data={ this.state.itemList }
                renderItem={ this._renderItem }
                >
            </FlatList>
        </View>
    );
}
```

The styles being applied:

```
cardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
},

card: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    flexBasis: '50%'
},
```

`_renderItem` is just a `<Card></Card>` with the `style={ card }` on it. I can post it if needed as well. But no major styling in there except for the inner elements.

Also, I noticed that when I scroll this FlatList, and if the list elements aren't taking the 100% of the vertical space, it looks like if it had an overflow: hidden with the max height of the parent container, how can I make this FlatList to be also 100% height no matter what?

This is what it's happening, not the desired outcome.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native FlatList with columns, Last item width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502954/react-native-flatlist-with-columns-last-item-width)

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right. Searched quite a lot and didnt find any specifically. Found the solution on the comments.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the possible duplicated that Rocky's suggested. I found a solution for my specific case and I also think it's the cleanest solution so far. Kudos to @Emilius Mfuruki.

There were a few other recommendations but adding `flex: 1/n` on the iterated item worked for me. So if you have 2 columns, it would be 1/2, if 3 would be 1/3 and so on.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: This doesn't always work. 1 / n is still bigger than the others due to padding...

Comment: use maxWidth : percent. percent should be 1/columns like 25%  if 4 columns and 50% if flatlist have 2 columns. and container view should have flex:no. of cokumns, i.e. flex:4 if there are 4 columns and item should be maxWIdth:"25%" and flex:1